# First time buyer in Ottawa and need some advice!

Tags: canada, first-time-home-buyer

Hi im thinking of buying a home in Ottawa south for 350,000$ and im going to put 25,000$ as a down payment. I will be moving to another country in 3 years so i will have to sell my home. Do you think i will make my money back or all the money will go on fees and taxes ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Generally I would expect to take a loss on something that short. Whether i't 's more or less than renting would cost you will depend on the exact property, how the market goes, how long it takes to find the buyer, how long you can afford to wait for a better offer, and the phase of the moon. A house you are living in is housing, not investment.

Comment: Generally, 3 years is a pretty short horizon to buy a house.

Comment: What those two guys said.